# Publishing Spykee's webcam images from URBI to ROS

Tags: ros

I successfully installed the Gostai firmware enabling URBI on Spykee.
Now, I would like to publish the camera images for ROS so that I can watch them on my PC. I saw this link but it seems I need to do the opposite.

### Did anyone try to achieve something similar ?

Fabien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROS implementation is not provided in the Gostai firmware due to CPU and size constraints.